# ListView with custom adapter that shows images and texts

Tags: android, listview

I want to have a list view that shows an Image and a text, so I followed an online tutorial. Unfortunately, my app keeps on crashing when I set the list view's adapter to the customAdapter. I couldn't figure out the crashing issue. 
Logcat:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
05-22 14:53:29.436 2592-2592/com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance, PID: 2592
                                                                                       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView


    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
at com.example.mohammadel_ghali.attendance.customAdapter.getView(customAdapter.java:48)
```

My customAdapter class

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Students>{

    public Context context;
    public int layoutResoruceId;
    public List<Students> data = null;


    public customAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Students> objects) {//constructor
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.layoutResoruceId=resource;
        this.data=objects;
    }

    public static class DataHolder{//class for holding the data
        ImageView ivPersonHolder;
        TextView tvNameHolder;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {//returns the "View"
        DataHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResoruceId, parent);
            holder = new DataHolder();
            holder.ivPersonHolder = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPerson);
            holder.tvNameHolder = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (DataHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        Students student = data.get(position);
        holder.tvNameHolder.setText(student.toString());
        holder.ivPersonHolder.setImageResource(student.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My itemrow xml layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPerson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/itemmargin"/>



  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/itemmargin"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting the adapter

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvStudentsList);
customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, R.layout.itemrow, students);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: the stacktrace is about another issue, put the right exception here

Comment: I edited my post, stating the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to override the `getCount` method in your `customAdapter` in order to `Android` know how many itens it have to display in `ListView`:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
```

Also, change this line,  because your `Adapter` does not allow adding new view:

```
convertView  = inflator.inflate(layoutResoruceId, parent);
```

to

```
convertView  = inflator.inflate(layoutResoruceId, null);
```

Comment: I added it, but still getting the same error. I have updated the exception in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter is unable to add new View.

**Just use:**

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResoruceId, null);
```

**Instead of:**

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResoruceId, parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was lying in this line (in customAdapter.java):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResoruceId, parent);
```

it should be:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResoruceId, null);
```

I really don't know why, but I would appreciate it if someone could give some sort of explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6887777/luiz-fernando-salvaterra for helping me out

Comment: Quick explanation: in that `inflate()` call, the second argument is the parent of the inflated `View`. If you provide that parent, the `LayoutInflater` will automatically add the inflated `View` to the parent with its `addView()`. The parent, in this case, is the `ListView`, which doesn't allow adding `View`s like that, thus the Exception. Passing `null` instead prevents the Inflater from automatically adding the `View` to anything. You should actually be using `inflator.inflate(layoutResoruceId, parent, false)`, so the inflated `View` respects the parent's properties, but still won't be added

Comment: Anyhoo, there's not really any need to add your own answer in this case. Simply accepting the answer as you did, and perhaps leaving a comment to indicate the actual, specific issue is sufficient. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike for the explanation and for the advice as well :). I certainly will take your advice into consideration while posting in the future. Cheers! :D